# Add time stamp tooltip to Notifications window

Tags: feature-request, notifications, stack-exchange-button

When you drop down that SE Genuine DropDown window, it would be nice to see the time stamp for that notification like you do for your inbox.

When I hover my mouse over an inbox message, I'll get something like "10 minutes ago", "May 18 at 12:50", etc.

But when you hover over a notification item...nothing.

Comment: Ummmm don't you mean the __StackExchange™ MultiCollider SuperDropdown™__? I have no idea what the _SE Genuine DropDown_ is....

Comment: I was thinking of this but was too lazy to post it